# VueJS allow only 1 checkbox select based on class name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox

I have group of checkboxes:

```
<div class="additions">
  <input type="checkbox" value="10" v-model="additional">
  <input type="checkbox" value="30" v-model="additional">
  <div class="group">
    <input type="checkbox" value="50" v-model="additional">
    <input type="checkbox" value="70" v-model="additional">
  </div>
</div>
```

I collecting checked values to data:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      additional: [],
    }
  },
});
```

Can't figure out how to prevent checking more then 1 checkbox **inside .group**
I tried using radio, but then stranger things come up, decided to stick with checkboxes. I could do it in jQuery or even vanilla JS I think, but I don't know where to put check (on change event method?). What is the best way to do it in VueJS?

Here is my pen: https://codepen.io/RomkaLTU/pen/LXOJgr?editors=1010

Comment: according to your codepen, I saw the lables Radio #1 and Radio #2, are they meant to be `type="radio"` rather than `type="checkbox"`?

Comment: Sorry not radio, it was at the beginning but then I decided to stick with checkboxes. That was question about.

Comment: check if this is what you are trying to achieve. https://codepen.io/Haeeb098/pen/eQebgz?editors=1011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me out, but I choosed solution without disabling input as it get's very confusing for the end user. What I did:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="30" v-model="additional">
<input type="checkbox" value="40" v-model="additional">
<input type="checkbox" value="10" v-model="additional_grouped" @change="uniqueCheck">
<input type="checkbox" value="20" v-model="additional_grouped" @change="uniqueCheck">


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      additional: [],
      additional_grouped: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    final: function(){
      return this.additional.concat(this.additional_grouped);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uniqueCheck(e){
      this.additional_grouped = [];
      if (e.target.checked) {
          this.additional_grouped.push(e.target.value);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use different ways:

**1. `:disabled` [directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)**

`<input type="checkbox" value="20" v-model="additional" :disabled="condition">`

Using condition like `additional.length > 0` you can disable checkbox if more then one already selected.

**2. [Watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)**

```
data() {
  ...
},
watch: {
  additional(newValue, oldValue) {
    // new additional array value will be here every time any checkbox switched
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don’t think about the DOM, don’t think about classes. Hard habit to break, I know.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="50" v-model="additional" :disabled="hasAdditional">

computed: {
  hasAdditional() {
    return this.additional.length > 0
  }
}
```

Use that as a starter for what you’re trying to do. Possibly you have to use a watcher to detect when it changes and uncheck ones that aren’t allowed. You could also change `hasAdditional` to return the sum of the number of additions, then use that to work if if you can select the group.

Don’t rely on CSS classes. Use methods, watchers, and computed properties to work the logic out.

Comment: wouldn't it disable the checkbox completely after selecting one and won't be able to select or deselect again?

Comment: Yes, that code isn’t complete, it’s a starter. I’m not completely sure of the functionality you’re trying to achieve so I can’t write the code for you. You could possibly have two data properties, and that if the first has more than 1 (as above), then the second set of checkboxes are disabled. Again, not sure what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function to clear the list of check boxes each time you select an option:

```
<div class="additions">
<input type="checkbox" value="10" v-model="additional" v-on:click= "check_one()">
<input type="checkbox" value="30" v-model="additional" v-on:click= "check_one()">
</div>
<script>
data(){
return {
additional: [], 
}
},
methods: {
check_one: function(){
this.additional = [];
}       
}
}
</script>
```